How to exclude the include_file_paths column from lazyframe without streaming
I cannot exclude the column when streaming=False
import tempfile
import polars as pl

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    pl.read_csv(b"a,b,c\n1,2,3").write_csv(f.name)
    f.seek(0)
    
    lf = pl.scan_csv(f.name, include_file_paths="file_path")
    
    print(lf.drop("file_path").collect())
    print(lf.drop("file_path").collect(streaming=True))

.collect()
shape: (1, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ file_path                       │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                             │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str                             │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ /var/folders/fq/6gcccvqd08v2px… │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

.collect(streaming=True)
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

How can I exclude the column without streaming?

What version of polars are you using? I cannot reproduce this using polars 1.9.0. In general, a MRE would be helpful to answer the question.

I'm using 1.9.0, forget to mention column that I want to exclude is column created by  pl.scan_csv(source, include_file_paths="column1")

Interesting. I am able to reproduce the issue with a sample CSV file. It might be worth raising a new issue on GitHub.

It seems to be a "bug" as @Hericks has pointed out. It works with projection_pushdown disabled. .collect(projection_pushdown=False)
